# How to solve Library not loaded error in Mac (M1) - PHP CLI

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, libtiff

I am getting this error when I try `php -v`

[image]

I have installed php using brew. I have following folders in `/opt/homebrew/opt` directory

- php
- php@7.3
- php@8.0
- php@8.1
- php@8.2

the output of `which php`:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/php
```

I tried following commands

`brew link php`

`brew install libtiff`

`brew reinstall libtiff`

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading brew error is solved.

`brew update`

`brew upgrade`

`brew doctor`

Comment: This worked after upgrading PHP to 8.2.11 via brew upgrade php on Ventura 13.4.1